# Issue file assets Libgdx

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx

I have a problem to load a file from assets.

In pratcise I have to load TiledMap file and I do it in this way:

```
arrayTiledMap.add(new TmxMapLoader().load(Gdx.files.internal("scenario.tmx").path())));
```

(I add it in array for other reason)

In the project the tmx file(scenario.tmx) is located in the android assets folder.
When I execute the program in Eclipse there aren't problems , but when I create the JAR file for Desktop project and I execute it I get this error on console(I launch it by terminal):

```
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: File not found:     Documents/University/Programming/Street.png (Internal)
```

The file `Street.png` is a file that I used in tiledMap editor for create the map.
At this point I check the JAR file contents and In the root directory of JAR there is the Documents folder and in it there is University folder and so on.

Because if the path is in the JAR file I get this error?

What is that wrong?

Thank you very much for your time, this error is driving me crazy

If you need other code, in particular, tell me.

(although I do not think since the problem only occurs when loading the file)

Comment: Can you also post the portion of code where you load Street.png file?

Answer (score 0):

> Because if the path is in the JAR file I get this error?

No. Its most likely you aren't exporting the JAR correctly.

**File -> Export -> Java -> Runnable JAR File**

And be sure to check this:

**package required libraries into generated JAR.**